# how to write a custom allocator for std::map in C++20

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++20, allocator

As I understand from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) we need to define `rebind_alloc` for our own custom allocator. But I did not really understand how I can let my own allocator also valid for the nodes of my map.

What I did:

```
template <class T>
class Allocator2
{
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t ;
        using propagate_on_container_move_assignment  = std::true_type;

        // no idea what I need for rebind_alloc here... ???
        template<typename U>
            using rebind_alloc = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator2<T>>::template rebind_alloc<U>;

        T* allocate(size_type n, const void* hint = 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Alloc" << n << std::endl;
            return static_cast<T*>(malloc(n*sizeof(T)));
        }

        void deallocate(T* p, size_type n) { free( p); }
        size_type max_size() const { return size_type(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() / sizeof(T)); }
        void construct(T* p, const T& value) { _construct(p, value); }
        void destroy(T* p) { _destroy(p); }
};

template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Allocator2 <T>&, const Allocator2 <U>&) noexcept { return true; }

template<class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Allocator2 <T>&, const Allocator2 <U>&) noexcept { return false; }

struct PointCmp {
    bool operator()(const int& lhs, const int& rhs ) const
    {   
        return lhs==rhs;
    }
};

    template < typename T>
void Print( T t)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using valueType = std::map< int, int>::value_type;
    Print( valueType{} );
    std::map< int, int , PointCmp, Allocator2< valueType>> m;

    for ( unsigned int n = 0; n<1000; n++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Now set " << n << std::endl;
        m[n]=n;
    }
}
```

Can someone point out what to set for `rebind_alloc`?
Maybe also a hint what is missing in addition to see nodes allocated for my map type?

Comment: There is a minimal custom allocator [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator#Examples) there. rebind_alloc is defined in [allocator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) not allocator: `rebind_alloc<T>`: `Alloc::rebind<T>::other if present, otherwise Alloc<T, Args> if this Alloc is Alloc<U, Args>`. you might need to define `rebind<U>` if your allocator has extra template parameters that cannot be deduced automatically.

Comment: @dewaffled: Can't see rebind_alloc in the example? Can't catch it!

Comment: @dewaffled: Even if I define `template <class Type> struct rebind { using other = Allocator2<Type>; }; my allocator is not used for the node at all. No idea how to get it work!

Comment: @Klaus: "*Can't see rebind_alloc in the example?*" The point is that you don't need to define it. You *may* need to define `rebind`, but only if you have special template parameters. "*my allocator is not used for the node at all*" How do you know that?

Comment: please do not remove includes from the code. They are part of the code, without them the code is incomplete and does not compile. I tried to get your code to compile, but i failed https://godbolt.org/z/vEb1e5fWb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to write a custom allocator ?

You just did that.

As others pointed out in comments `rebind_alloc` is not needed for your allocator.

Your comparator is broken however. As the map checks for equivalence via `! comp(a,b) && ! comp(b,a)`, with your comparator, any two element are considered equivalent unless they are equal. Thats not right. Perhaps thats why you concluded there would be something wrong with your allocator. Though, when all numbers are equivalent, it is correct to insert only the first and not the others.

Note that there is no need to define a custom comparator when you can use `std::less<>`.

Fixing that and adding the includes your allocater works as expected:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <map>

template <class T>
class Allocator2
{
    public:
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t ;
        using propagate_on_container_move_assignment  = std::true_type;

       
        T* allocate(size_type n, const void* hint = 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Alloc" << n << std::endl;
            return static_cast<T*>(malloc(n*sizeof(T)));
        }

        void deallocate(T* p, size_type n) { free( p); }
        size_type max_size() const { return size_type(std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() / sizeof(T)); }
        void construct(T* p, const T& value) { _construct(p, value); }
        void destroy(T* p) { _destroy(p); }
};

template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Allocator2 <T>&, const Allocator2 <U>&) noexcept { return true; }

template<class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Allocator2 <T>&, const Allocator2 <U>&) noexcept { return false; }

struct PointCmp {
    bool operator()(const int& lhs, const int& rhs ) const
    {   
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

    template < typename T>
void Print( T t)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    using valueType = std::map< int, int>::value_type;
    Print( valueType{} );
    std::map< int, int , std::less<>, Allocator2< valueType>> m;

    for ( unsigned int n = 0; n<10; n++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Now set " << n << std::endl;
        m[n]=n;
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5K6ebs4vd)

Comment: "Though, when all numbers are equivalent, it is correct to insert only the first and not the others." :-) ! Great observation. You are right. I thought it starts allocating some stuff for the map at the beginning but not for the nodes later on... Thanks for your work!